# My Bluetooth receiver will not connect as an audio device

Tags: bluetooth

I have a Yamaha AX-a660 reciever and I am trying to bluetooth connect it to a Lenovo laptop in the Y50 family running windows 10 (with the latest updates).

Settings > Bluetooth > Add Bluetooth or other device, will only connect as "Everything else" and not as an audio device and it won't play the music on the Yamaha.

The oddity is that the problem is only with my Lenovo. The Yamaha connects fine to my Surface Go running windows 10, an android phone, iphones and ipads - so clearly the Yamaha is setup correctly.

I tried updating the bluetooth drivers on the Lenovo. I tried deleting drivers rebooting and letting the system find its own drivers, all to no avail.

I can connect the Yamaha to the Lenovo directly to Spotify using the Spotify device connection (paid spotify), but that only works for Spotify and not any other media program such as You Tube.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you connected it to Spotify before trying to connect by windows? It might be possible that spotify somehow keeps a link active that prevents windows from seeing the device, and you must unpair it through spotify first.

Comment: I thought of that, and disconnected from Spotify - shut it down, rebooted ... no difference.